# Como salvar Disicplina?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4

Tenho o seguinte problema na minha aplicação.A tabela curso é relacionada com a tabela Disciplina, ou seja, 1 Disciplina pertence a vários curso, e na hora de  cadastrar um curso e adicionar mais disciplinas a este curso eu não consigo realizar esta ação.
Print das telas:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
[Controller]
public ActionResult AddDisciplina(int id, Curso curso) { 
    @ViewBag.id = curso.CursoID=id; 
    ViewBag.d = new SelectList(db.disciplina, "DisciplinaID", "nome"); 
    return View(); 
}

[HttpPost, ActionName("AddDisciplina")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddDisciplina([Bind(Include = "CursoID,DisciplinaID")]Curso curso)
{
    return View();
}

[View]
<h2>AddDisciplina</h2> 
<div class="form-group"> 
     <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10"> 
         <input type="hidden" id=" cursoID" name="cursoID" value="@ViewBag.id"> 
         @Html.DropDownList("d", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" }) 
     </div> 
</div> 
<br/> 
<div class="form-group"> 
     <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10"> 
          <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" /> 
     </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Você pode colocar na sua pergunta o código que realiza essa inserção?

Comment: Cadê a `Action` que persiste os dados? Dica: Também chama `AddDiscipina`, mas tem um `[HttpPost]` em cima.

Answer (score 3):

Não tem nada na sua `Action` pra salvar. Obviamente não vai funcionar.

Tem que ser algo assim:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("AddDisciplina")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddDisciplina([Bind(Include = "CursoID,DisciplinaID")]Curso curso)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var disciplina = db.Disciplinas.SingleOrDefault(d => d.DisciplinaID == DisciplinaID);
        var curso = new Curso {
            Disciplina = disciplina
        };

        context.Cursos.Add(curso);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    return View();
}
```